# Ring of invariants preserves normality

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

Suppose we have a normal domain $R$ (i.e. integrally closed in its field of fractions) with a group $G$ acting on it by ring homomorphisms.

> I was wondering how one could prove that the ring of $G$-invariants $R^{G}=\{r \in R \mid gr = r ,  \; \forall g \in G \}$ is also a normal domain.

Comment: Do you assume that $G$ is finite?

Comment: @AlexWertheim No, G is arbitrary (I believe this still holds)

Comment: An integral element of the fraction field of $R^G$ must lie in $R$ and also be $G$-invariant, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ denote the field of fractions of $R^G$.  Then if $z\in k$ and $z$ is integral over $R^G$, then $z$ lies in the field of fractions of $R$ and is integral over $R$, so $z\in R$.

Thus we have $x,y\in R^G$ with $y\neq 0$ such that $\frac xy=z$, with $z\in R$.  Thus $x=yz$.

For any $g\in G$, we may apply $g$ to both sides and obtain $x=yg(z)$.  Thus $$yg(z)=x=yz.$$
As $y\neq 0$, we may conclude $g(z)=z$.

Thus $z\in R^G$ as required.